# install shield 2012 professional skin customization kit fails

Tags: customization, installshield, skin

I have inherited a install shield project that was using 2010.  I upgraded to **2012 IS professional.**

I also downloaded the skin customization kit which encounters the following problem. I am trying to use this customization kit to generate new skin file as

```
CreateSkinFile.exe C:\MySkinFilesSrc C:\CustomizedSkins\setup.isn
```

It opens and closes immediately. There is no scope of reading the error that it displayed as it opens a new window and closes in a sub-second. There is no log, no trace on what exactly it is complaining.

Is there any way to trouble shoot this and see what the problem is? The **ini** file is in order per the customization kit guidelines.

btw: I wanted to make sure that I am doing the right thing.  I took one of their clown examples and tried to generate a skin using it.  That also fails in a similar way.  Added to that I used the skin customization kit to extract and used the same exacted ones to make a skin and that fails too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have found and i hope it helps others.

The kit is written very poorely, as it does not have any verbose or proper error reporting.  It opens and closes so fast a human cannot read.  Having said that i found that:

1. The kit that the account representative gave me is for 2012 Spring.  Once i rectified that, the problem remains.
2. The root cause is that, one of images in the skin file does not exist.  I have number of images, and i was not careful to look at every one of them.  Once i went through and made sure every image is present in the directory, the CreateSkinFile went ahead and generated the ISN file successfully.

Hope it helps some one else.